# Module has been externalized for browser compatibility error in Vite build

Tags: vue.js, aem, vite

I am currently working on a project that utilizes **Vite version 4.3.2** and is integrated with Adobe Experience Manager **(AEM)** via the **aem-vite** plugin. The project also includes '@aem-vite/vite-aem-plugin' and '@aem-vite/import-rewriter'.

The issue I'm facing is that the project works fine on the dev server but throws an error when I build for production. The error message I get in the browser console is:

> Module "" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot
> access ".custom" in client code.

The **Module ""** part doesn't provide clarity on what actual module might be causing this issue.

Here is my entire vite.config.ts file:

```js
    export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => ({
      plugins: [
        vue(),
        vueJsx(),
        tsconfigPaths(),
        viteForAem({
          contentPaths: [designsName, 'content'],
          publicPath: clientLibsPath,
        }),
        bundlesImportRewriter({
          publicPath: clientLibsPath,
          resourcesPath: 'resources/js',
        }),
        commonjs({
          include: '/node_modules/',
          requireReturnsDefault: 'auto',
          defaultIsModuleExports: 'auto',
        }),
      ],
      optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['qs', 'dayjs'],
      },
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL(clientScriptsPath, import.meta.url)),
          'aem-base': aemBaseClientPath(),
          ...createLibMock('lib/proxyImport', 'proxyImport'),
          ...createLibMock('components/mixins/isMobile', 'isMobile'),
          components: aemBaseClientPath('scripts/components'),
          constants: aemBaseClientPath('scripts/constants'),
          lib: aemBaseClientPath('scripts/lib'),
        },
        dedupe: ['vue'],
      },
      base: command === 'build' ? clientlibsFolderPath : '/',
      root: './',
      build: {
        brotliSize: false,
        manifest: false,
        minify: mode === 'development' ? false : 'esbuild',
        outDir: 'dist',
        sourcemap: command === 'serve' ? 'inline' : false,
        rollupOptions: {
          output: {
            assetFileNames: `${clientlibResourcesPath}/[ext]/[name][extname]`,
            chunkFileNames: `${clientlibResourcesPath}/chunks/[name].[hash].js`,
            entryFileNames: `${clientlibResourcesPath}/js/[name].js`,
          },
          input: {
            bundle: `${clientPath}/scripts/main.ts`,
            styles: `${clientPath}/assets/styles/main.scss`,
          },
        },
      },
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `$s-base-resource-path: "${aemBaseResourcePath}";$s-selectiontools-resource-path: "${clientLibsPath}";`,
            quietDeps: true,
          },
        },
        loaderOptions: {
          sass: {
            quietDeps: true,
          },
        },
      },
      test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude],
        root: `${clientScriptsPath}/tests`,
        coverage: {
          reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html', 'lcov'],
          reportsDirectory: `${testReportsPath}`,
        },
      },
    }));
```

Here is the section of my vite.config.js where I've set up aliases in an attempt to fix this:

```
resolve: {
alias: {
    process: "process/browser",
    buffer: "buffer",
    crypto: "crypto-browserify",
    stream: "stream-browserify",
    assert: "assert",
    http: "stream-http",
    https: "https-browserify",
    os: "os-browserify",
    url: "url",
    util: "util",
},
```

Despite this, I'm still receiving the same error.

I've already tried upgrading and downgrading the Vite version, but the issue persists. Is there something I'm missing or not understanding here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can try using the vite-plugin-node plugin. This plugin helps resolve the Node.js core modules automatically during the build process.

Comment: @dekts thanks for the tip, but I am using AEM, so vite-plugin-node would probably not work.

Answer (score 9):

Install ***[vite-plugin-node-polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills)***:

`npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills`

or
`yarn add --dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills`

and add `nodePolyfills()` to vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid these warnings by using a polyfill node package like `rollup-plugin-node-polyfills` and use it in your alias settings:

```js
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            util: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
            assert: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert",
            os: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os",
            buffer: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/buffer-es6",
            process: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6",
            fs: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/empty",
            net: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/empty",
            perf_hooks: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/empty",
            path: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path",
            child_process: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/empty",
        },
    },
```

For non-existing polyfills or when you are sure the code that imports a specific Node.js module is never executed in the browser, use the `empty` "polyfill".

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of modules with dependencies for code paths I won't use - eg, old slow blockchains that I don't use, or node-specific code that I know will never run in the browser. `empty` was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Install vite-plugin-node-polyfills

`npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills`

or `yarn add --dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills`

and add the import `import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";`

to vite.config.ts and add `nodePolyfills()` to `nodePolyfills()`